# How to save a yasnippet placeholder's final value in an Elisp variable?

Tags: major-mode, yasnippet

In its more recent versions, `shell-script` mode tailors its behavior in response to the `sh-shell` variable's value, which indicates the shell variant (`zsh`, `bash`, etc.) that the script is for.

I've written this simple snippet (for `shell-script` mode) that uses the value of `sh-shell`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: shebang
# key: shebang
# --
#!/usr/bin/env ${1:`(symbol-name sh-shell)`}
# -*- mode: shell-script ; sh-shell: $1 -*-
```

After one types `shebang<TAB>`, and assuming that `sh-shell` is set to `bash`, the following text is inserted

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# -*- mode: shell-script ; sh-shell: bash -*-
```

...with the cursor positioned at the beginning of the first `bash`.

At this point one has the option to type the name of a different shell, which would replace both occurrences of `bash`.

Is there a way to modify the snippet so that, once the value of the `$1` field is finalized, this value is stored in `sh-shell`?  In this way the snippet would serve, in addition to inserting some text, as a way to re-set `sh-shell` to a new value.

---

I know that I can always run `M-x normal-mode` after updating the `$1` field, to have Emacs read the new buffer mode settings from the `-*- ... -*-` line, but it'd be nice to get the same end-result automatically once the snippet is finalized.

Comment: Should be doable with a transform using ` yas-moving-away-p`